# Sending variable to a layout through constructur

Tags: layout, laravel

I'm trying to pass an array to layout appears on all pages without having to add it to any function controller . I thought maybe the construct can do it but I'm having an error . What am I not doing right?

Thanks for the help

```
 public function __construct(){

$data = array ('online' => $this->Checkonline());


return View::make('layout.navigation')->with('online', $data);

}

public function Checkonline() {

 $data = DB::table('users')->where('online', '=', '1')->get();


 return $data;


 }
```

layout.navigation:

```
@foreach ($online as $user_online)

      {{  $user_online->username  }}

       @endforeach
```

Comment: Please post what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot do this. You need to return response in controller method that is used as route, so you should do:

```
public function Checkonline() 
{
    $data = DB::table('users')->where('online', '=', '1')->get();
    return View::make('layout.navigation')->with('online', $data);
}
```